# Align the footnote markers to the right in footnotes

Tags: footnotes

my footnotes are justified hanging footnotes that work well, but I would like a bit more:

since the footnote number takes a variable space, depending on whether it is a one-digit or two-digit number, I would like to have the footnote number flushed right inside its own "space", i.e. still indented 8pt, but footnote numbers  will "grow" flushed right, so keeping a constant separation from the first letter of the footnote text.

Code example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true] {hyperref}

\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{8pt}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10pt}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{7mm}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}

Footnotes with flush align left of their footnote marks\footnote{first footnote}.
But I want them aligned right on their marks\footnote{second footnote .... OOO}
Simple sentences talking about attenuators and\footnote{Available somewhere}
bearing a lot of footnotes\footnote{yet another footnote}
bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnote{it's getting boring}
attenuator is useful\footnote{yes, right}
attenuator is beautiful\footnote{oh, yeah ...} and
bla bla bla\footnote{we are almost there} bla bla bla bla
and is also cheap\footnote{not all of them}.
But I want to save money\footnote{Who does not??}
and I will build one... or two\footnote{here we are}.
That's it\footnote{last footnote}, now we have more than 10 footontes!

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is quite what you want but perhaps it is close. You can redefine `\thefootnote` so that it is within its' own little box and push the number to the righthand side using:

```
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\hbox to 6pt{\hss\arabic{footnote}}}
```

This now gives footnotes like this:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true] {hyperref}

\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{8pt}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10pt}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{7mm}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\hbox to 6pt{\hss\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

Footnotes with flush align left of their footnote marks\footnote{first footnote}.
But I want them aligned right on their marks\footnote{second footnote .... OOO}
Simple sentences talking about attenuators and\footnote{Available somewhere}
bearing a lot of footnotes\footnote{yet another footnote}
bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnote{it's getting boring}
attenuator is useful\footnote{yes, right}
attenuator is beautiful\footnote{oh, yeah ...} and
bla bla bla\footnote{we are almost there} bla bla bla bla
and is also cheap\footnote{not all of them}.
But I want to save money\footnote{Who does not??}
and I will build one... or two\footnote{here we are}.
That's it\footnote{last footnote}, now we have more than 10 footontes!

\end{document}
```

Comment: -Thanks! Perfect. Now that I see the \hss it is a bit more clear, simply because I have browsed with the right hint. Just to understand: you create a \hbox of 6pt and have variable stretch/shrink, and I will see a gap of my 8pt - your 6pt = 2 pt between the mark and the footnote text, right? But how you get the flushed right alignment? it is a default or it has to do with "to"?

Comment: Well, no! Also the footnote markers in text will use the same code!

Comment: @egreg -Ok, I definitely need to study basic Tex grammar for some days and make some experiments! I would like to understand what I am doing and book formatting is the good occasion. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change how the footnote markers are placed in the footnotes. The code does

```
\hbox to \footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}
```

so it's sufficient to say

```
\hbox to \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark\hspace{4pt}}
```

after enlarging a bit the `\footnotemargin`; I set it to 12pt. Fix the lengths to your liking.

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}

\setlength\footnotemargin{12pt}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10pt}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{7mm}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}
  {\@makefnmark\hss}
  {\hss\@makefnmark\hspace{4pt}}
  {}{}
\makeatletter

% just to show all text and footnotes without a wide white space
\setlength{\textheight}{10cm} 

\begin{document}

Footnotes with flush align left of their footnote marks\footnote{first footnote}.
But I want them aligned right on their marks\footnote{second footnote .... OOO}
Simple sentences talking about attenuators and\footnote{Available somewhere}
bearing a lot of footnotes\footnote{yet another footnote}
bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnote{it's getting boring}
attenuator is useful\footnote{yes, right}
attenuator is beautiful\footnote{oh, yeah ...} and
bla bla bla\footnote{we are almost there} bla bla bla bla
and is also cheap\footnote{not all of them}.
But I want to save money\footnote{Who does not??}
and I will build one... or two\footnote{here we are}.
That's it\footnote{last footnote which is very long and splits across lines,
  just to see what's the effect. This should be long enough}, now we have 
more than 10 footnotes!

\end{document}
```

[image]