# Align multiple line footnote text

Tags: align, footnotes

I am trying to align the footnote text to the right of the number but I cannot get it working. I tried with both codes mentioned in the following answer: [How can I align a multiple-line footnote text right to the footnote mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126877/how-can-i-align-a-multiple-line-footnote-text-right-to-the-footnote-mark). The result remains the same. See screenshot and MWE below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}


\begin{document}
Bien qu'une partie de la doctrine\footnote{ROBERT (L.), « L’accord autonome, nouveau symbole des dérives des contrats de partenariat ? », \textit{JCP / LA SEMAINE JURIDIQUE – ÉDITION ADMINISTRATIONS ET COLLECTIVITÉS TERRITORIALES}, N° 48 1er décembre 2014 p. 2337} s'interroge sur la légalité
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be caused by `usepackage[francais]{babel}` but I do not know why.

Comment: For future reference: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236781/align-the-footnote-markers-to-the-right-in-footnotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the `babel` handling for French footnotes:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\begin{document}
Bien qu'une partie de la doctrine\footnote{ROBERT (L.), \enquote{L’accord autonome, nouveau symbole des dérives des contrats de partenariat?}, \textit{JCP / LA SEMAINE JURIDIQUE – ÉDITION ADMINISTRATIONS ET COLLECTIVITÉS TERRITORIALES}, N°~48 1er décembre 2014 p.~2337} s'interroge sur la légalité
\end{document}
```